# Optimization code in R, am I missing something?

Tags: r, optimization

I'm trying to optimize the parameters of a simple strategy as the code below by maximizing the sharpe ratio. The output results are clearly wrong. Can you please provide some help?

```
library(xts)
library(zoo)
library(quantmod)
library(PerformanceAnalytics)
library(TTR)

f_opt <- function(x, data){

a <- x[1]
b <- x[2]

sma <- SMA(Cl(data), n = a)
fma <- EMA(Cl(data), n = b)
signal <- Lag(ifelse(sma < fma, 1, -1))
ret <- Return.calculate(data, method = "discrete") * signal
colnames(ret) <- c("MA Strategy")
ret <- na.omit(ret)

sharpe <- SharpeRatio.annualized(ret, Rf = 0, scale = 252) * -1
return(as.numeric(sharpe))

}

SYMBL <- getSymbols("^GSPC", auto.assign=F, from="2011-01-01", to="2021-02-08") 
data <- na.omit(SYMBL[,4])

optim(par = c(1,1), fn = f_opt, data = data, method = "L-BFGS-B", lower = 1, upper = 200)
```

OUTPUT

[1] 1.869527 1.000000

$value
[1] -0.6721263

$counts
function gradient
7        7

$convergence
[1] 0

$message
[1] "CONVERGENCE: NORM OF PROJECTED GRADIENT <= PGTOL"

Comment: yes, thats why the * -1 at the end

Comment: I also see that your lower bound is 1 and your starting values are 1s. Boundaries are tricky and can have weird behavior. Have you tried other starting values?

Comment: I did and get the same incorrect values. I also always get as output the same starting value for b

Comment: Can you explain what is "clearly wrong" about the results? The `convergence 0` in the output indicates `optim` thinks it was successful, and getting the same result from different starting values shows that it is relatively robust.

Comment: the function is clearly not minimized, just try a few for and b and you can find a higher sharpe than the out put

Comment: take a = 20 and b = 20, sharpe is 0 ... higher than the optimization output

Comment: This goes back to the `* -1` -- optim is minimizing, so `-0.2179` means a Sharpe ratio of `+0.2179`, which is higher than 0.

Comment: i copied the wrong output actually but in this case it is higher but I tried with other asset and I can easily find better combination than the optim output... it seems that one the parameters always get stuck at the initial value too

Comment: if you use ^BVSP instead of ^GSPC, I can find sharpe of 0.61 with a = 50 and b = 21, while the optim output is sharpe 0.21 with a = 1.4732 and b = 1 ... note that b is locked at 1.

Comment: also, can I make steps as 1? integer

Comment: No, optim is for continuous optimization. And as I said before, don't start at the boundaries.

Comment: If you have a discrete optimization problem, you should use another method - optim is using gradients, which may be behaving weirdly at non-integer values if this is a discrete problem. If your possible ranges are actually 1:200 for 2 variables, you might as well do a grid search, compute all 40000 possibilities and pick the best - it's not so many.

Comment: Hey Gregor and Ben, have I told you guys rock big time? Happy to learn from you. Thanks and take care.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`optim()` and related methods can find optima of **smooth** surfaces. With only two parameters it's easy enough to compute the objective function over a surface by brute force (I use functions from the `emdbook` and `plot3D` packages for convenience, but you could easily do this with `for()` loops and the built-in `persp()` function ...) (code below)

[image: extremely rough objective function surface]

I know nothing about your subject area (finance?) or what's going on under the hood in the objective function, but it's not at all surprising that the optimization didn't work.

I was concerned that maybe the problem was with non-integer values of the parameters (which would present a problem for `optim()` in any case, but might suggest other approaches), but even restricting to integer values in the range (5-20, 180-200) we still get a rough-looking surface:

[image: another rough surface]

I have found the `DEoptim` (optimization by differential evolution) function useful for problems like this.

```
d1 <- DEoptim(f_opt, data=data,lower=c(1,1),upper=c(200,200))
## $optim
## $optim$bestmem
##      par1      par2 
##  12.87796 190.91548 
## 
## $optim$bestval
## [1] -1.158693
```

```r
library(emdbook)
## this step takes a while
system.time(
    cc <- curve3d(f_opt(c(x,y), data=data),
                  from=c(1,1),to=c(200,200),
                  n=61,
                  sys3d="none",
                  .progress="text")
)

## Cairo::Cairo(file="plot3d.png")

library(plot3D)
with(cc,persp3D(x=replicate(61,x),
               y=t(replicate(61,y)),
               z,
               border="black")
     )

## dev.off()


cc2 <- curve3d(f_opt(c(x,y), data=data),
               from=c(5,180),to=c(20,200),
               n=c(16,21),
               sys3d="none",
               .progress="text")

## Cairo::Cairo(file="plot3dB.png",width=1280,height=960)
with(cc2,persp3D(x=replicate(21,x),
                y=t(replicate(16,y)),
                cc2$z,
                border="black"))
## dev.off()
```

Comment: Hey Ben, have I told you guys rock big time? Happy to learn from you. Yes my area is finance, I’m at very beginning of building a framework to backtest trading strategies. Thanks and take care.